# how to get images related to each song using cursor?

Tags: android

```
//this method returns me name of song.
     private void getMusic() {
         String[] STAR = { "*"};
         Cursor cursor;
         Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
         String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
         cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, STAR, selection, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int i = 0;
            do {
                   //this returns name of the song
                String songName = cursor.getString(cursor.
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                  //this returns path of the song
                path[i] = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                 //this returns album name of the song
                String albumName = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                 //this returns albumid of the song
                int albumId = cursor.getInt(cursor                                                          
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)); 
                 //this will add song in listview
                song.add(songName);
                i++;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            b = i;
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code in  this question.

Comment: pls add some details to your question, not only the code. I tried to improve the formatting of your code.

Comment: this is continues code and i am using above method to get name of song from sdcard . song is my list . I want to add the image that every song has when we play it in audio player.

Comment: All that you already extract from the DB is a text information. But image is not text information. It is called Artwork by the way. That image is attached to the file metadata, and is not stored in Android DB. You will have to extract it from file directly

Comment: can u share any example??@VladMatvienko